# Get feedback and make it visual

Tags: sharepoint-designer, survey

I have a calendar with events. When a event ends an email should be sent out, with a survey to get feedback. It is always the same questions no matter what event type.
I first thought the app "Survey" would be good for that, but it seems like it has no value for me because I can't filter the answers to what event the user went.
Is there a way to filter the answers in a way to seperate events?

So I need have for example 4 questions:

What event did you attend?

How do you rate the topic?

How do you rate the lecturer?

How do you rate the learning materials?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Create simple list with choice type fields and filter it. In emails send link to `NewForm.aspx` of your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of what I'd do -

1. Create a separate custom list (Survey) with all the columns you mentioned.
2. Include a lookup column in your list created above, that points to
   your original calendar event. (Users will have to manually select
   this field when they fill out the survey. Incase, you wish to
   enforce this as automation/prefilled data, you will have to use some
   CSOM scripts or event receivers)
3. When the event ends, send out an email to the
   specified users containing the link of the list you created above in
   Step 1. (via. Event receiver, etc.)